# Multiple thread failed to execute the nonsynchronized code in java

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

If Thread1 get the lock and start executing the synchronized block, During the same time,Thread2 is free to execute the non-synchronized part of the code which is `IntStream.range(0, 5).forEach(x -> System.out.println("thread Unsafe Zone,"+name))`.

**Unexpectedly,below is what actually happening while i run code.**

Explaintation-

Suppose,thread1(or thread2) get the lock and execute the synchronized block and then thread2( or thread1) get the lock released by thread1(or thread2) and execute the synchronized block.After both thread complete the execution of synchronized block, then both thread parellelly start executing the non-synchronized part. I run the code multiple time hoping to get the desired output but fail to avail.

Demo class

```
public class Demo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Display d=new Display("AnyName");
        Thread1 t1=new Thread1(d);
        Thread2 t2=new Thread2(d);
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
    }
}
```

Thread1 class

```
public class Thread1 extends Thread {
    Display d;
    Thread1(Display d) {
        this.d = d;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
       d.getname("Thread 1");
    }
}
```

Thread2 class

```
public class Thread2 extends Thread {
    Display d;

    Thread2(Display d) {
        this.d = d;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
            d.getname("Thread 2");
    }
}
```

Display class

```
public class Display {
    String name;

    public Display(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void getname(String name)  {
        synchronized (this) {
            IntStream.range(0, 5).forEach((idx) -> {
                System.out.println(name);
            });
            this.name=name;
        }

        IntStream.range(0, 5).forEach(x -> System.out.println("thread Unsafe Zone,"+name));// this line
//get executed only after the synchronized method completed by both thread

    }
}
```

Output:

```
Thread 2
Thread 2
Thread 2
Thread 2
Thread 2
Thread 1
Thread 1
Thread 1
Thread 1
Thread 1
thread Unsafe Zone,Thread 2
thread Unsafe Zone,Thread 1
thread Unsafe Zone,Thread 2
thread Unsafe Zone,Thread 1
thread Unsafe Zone,Thread 2
thread Unsafe Zone,Thread 1
thread Unsafe Zone,Thread 1
thread Unsafe Zone,Thread 2
thread Unsafe Zone,Thread 1
thread Unsafe Zone,Thread 2
```

Comment: there is more than one cpu/core correct? If so then sometimes you would see an interleaving where one thread begins execution of the non-synchronized. Try to put a sleep in the synchronized and then you would see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*If Thread1 get the lock and start executing the synchronized block, During the same time,Thread2 is free to execute the non-synchronized part of the code*: not exactly.

In execution order the non-synchronized block follows the synchronized block. Therefore you will never see any thread executing the non-synchronized block before the synchronized block.

The best what you can hope for is something like

```
Thread 1
Thread 1
Thread 1
Thread 1
Thread 1
thread Unsafe Zone,Thread 1
thread Unsafe Zone,Thread 1
thread Unsafe Zone,Thread 1
Thread 2
Thread 2
Thread 2
Thread 2
Thread 2
thread Unsafe Zone,Thread 1
thread Unsafe Zone,Thread 1
thread Unsafe Zone,Thread 2
thread Unsafe Zone,Thread 2
thread Unsafe Zone,Thread 2
thread Unsafe Zone,Thread 2
thread Unsafe Zone,Thread 2
```

where the thread 2 enters the synchronized block while thread 1 is running in the non-synchronized block.

You can increase the chance for such an outcome by changing your `Display.getname()` method by calling `Thread.yield();` after the synchronized block and by doing more `System.out.println()` calls:

```
public void getname(String name)  {
    synchronized (this) {
        IntStream.range(0, 5).forEach((idx) -> {
            System.out.println(name);
        });
        this.name=name;
    }
    Thread.yield();

    IntStream.range(0, 20).forEach(x -> System.out.println("thread Unsafe Zone,"+name));

}
```

Comment: @ManishSharma No, and the sample output shows that: Thread 1 starts executing the non-synchronized block (and prints 3 times "thread Unsafe Zone,Thread 1") before Thread 2 enters the synchronized block. What I wanted to say: in a method (like `getname()`) if you have a code block A followed by a code block B then each thread will always execute A first and only then execute B. Your question seems to imply that you expect the second thread to execute B before A, but that will never happen.